# Three.js new THREE.TextBufferGeometry() Cannot read property 'yMax' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'yMax' of undefined" when adding text to a three.js scene.

```
let loader = new THREE.FontLoader();

  let font = loader.parse( jsonFont );

  let geometry = new THREE.TextBufferGeometry( 'MY TEXT', {
        font: font,
        size: 80,
        height: 5,
        curveSegments: 12,
        bevelEnabled: true,
        bevelThickness: 10,
        bevelSize: 8,
        bevelSegments: 5
  } );
```

Chrome browser complete console error reads:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'yMax' of undefined <-- createPaths    <-- generateShapes  <-- TextBufferGeometry

Comment: `m_scene.add( font );` What do you do this for?

Comment: I took that from the official documentation, I think it's unnecessary but added it just in case...

Comment: I removed m_scene.add( font );

Comment: What is `jsonFont`? What value in it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solutions to my problems.

**Solution source:**
https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_text_shapes
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_geometry_text_shapes.html

**My code mistake:**
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/13665

|---------------|

This code worked for me:

```
let loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader.load( "/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json", ( font ) =>
{
  let xMid;
  let shapes = font.generateShapes( "Sample Test", 100, 2 );

  let textShape = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  let geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry( shapes );
  geometry.computeBoundingBox();

  let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
                                               color      : 0x006699,
                                               transparent: true,
                                               opacity    : 0.4,
                                               side       : THREE.DoubleSide
                                             } );

  xMid = -0.5 * ( geometry.boundingBox.max.x - geometry.boundingBox.min.x );
  geometry.translate( xMid, 0, 0 );

  textShape.fromGeometry( geometry );
  let mesh = new THREE.Mesh( textShape, material );
  m_scene.add( mesh );

} );
```